# Condition in operator=

Tags: c++, architecture

Consider I have an object of type `B` which contains an object of type `A`. And `A` contains an integer which cannot be changed. From `B` `A` is returned by non-const reference (because it contains some useful methods):

```
class A {
private:
    int i;
public:
    A(int i) : i(i) {};

    void doSomethingNonConst() {}

    int getInt() {
        return i;
    }
}

class B {
public:
    A& getA();
}
```

But there's a problem: I can do something like the following: `getA() = A(5);` which of course changes the integer that cannot be changed.
My solution is do something with `operator=`, namely **to copy only when destination's and source's integers are equal**, otherwise throw an exception:

```
A& operator=(const A& a) {
    if (a.i == i) {
        //do copy
    } else
        //throw an exception
}
```

Is it good design solution? If it isn't, then how can I do it better? Maybe, it's better to copy everything but add some checks for integers equality in outer code?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you're a kind of genius. Thank you

Comment: It's a bad design because the error only shows up at runtime. Using const types shows up at compile time and is preferable. Why not make the `int i` const?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could do that, it is likely to confuse people, and you would have to handle it at run time. Often it is more desirable to get an error at compile time and just prevent "copying" entirely.

In this case you could make the integer `const`, which would prevent the implicit default copy operator.

```
class A {
private:
    const int i;
public:
    A(int i) : i(i) {};

    void doSomethingNonConst() {}

    int getInt() {
        return i;
    }
};
class B {
public:
    B() : a(5) {}
    A &getA() { return a; } // still non-const here
private:
    A a;
};
int main()
{
    B b;
    A otherA(60);
    // Compile error. GCC: use of deleted function 'A& A::operator=(const A&)'
    // 'A& A::operator=(const A&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed
    b.getA() = otherA;
}
```

Otherwise you can get rid of the operators explicitly, e.g. if you can't make the variables const for some other reason. In some cases it might also be desirable to prevent copying via the *copy constructor*, which works the same way.

You can do that by deleting the default operators `A &operator = (const A &) = delete;`.

```
class A {
private:
    int i;
public:
    A(int i) : i(i) {};

    A (const A &) = delete;
    A &operator = (const A &) = delete;

    void doSomethingNonConst() {}

    int getInt() {
        return i;
    }
};
int main()
{
    B b;
    A otherA(60);
    b.getA() = otherA; // Compile error. GCC: use of deleted function 'A& A::operator=(const A&)'
}
```

Comment: Do i need to delete move `operator=` too?

Comment: Not in addition. By deleting or having the copy, you won't get the default move (if you did want it in some situation, use `A& operator = (A &&) = default;`). See [cppreference Implicitly-declared move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) for when the implicit operator is created and [move constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).

Answer (score 2):

> And A contains an integer which cannot be changed.

Then either make that `int` `const`:

```
class A {
private:
    const int i;
...
```

and/or make the `A` in `B` `const` and return a `const` reference::

```
class B {
private:
    const A a;
public:
    const A& getA();
}
```

Comment: The second solution is unacceptable because as I said `A` contains some useful and needed non-const methods. But I'll accept the answer.

Comment: You can make those some needed members mutable, a mutable member can be modified by const method and const object.

Comment: @wcobalt Sound like you should have two (or more) classes then.

Comment: @PaulEvans why and what the classes do i need?

Comment: @PaulEvans and what to do if I need that integer non-const (because IRL it's not an integer but an object which also contains some needed non-const methods)?

Comment: @wcobalt A single `class` should serve a single purpose, it sound like you're stretching multiple purposes over one `class`. A rethink in your design may be in order.